# How do I enter interactive command mode in GRUB bootloader?

Tags: grub

I've accidentally locked myself out of the sudoers file on my desktop machine when trying to get wireshark working.

So I figured that I need to enter single user mode.  I've read how to do it in grub, but I can't seem to get the grub menu to appear in my default kubuntu installation.

It is hidden.  How do I make it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during computer boot up, Grub will display its menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get into the menu.